# Wix bootstrapper's "/layout" option

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

Can a custom wix bootstrapper make use of the /layout option in order to extract compressed packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `/layout` is just for downloading packages that aren't compressed into the bundle .exe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the engine expose the ability to extract the packages through our own custom code?

Comment: You can cache the packages without installing them but it will require elevation to write to the per-machine package cache.